# Is there a way to plot 2x Standard Deviation in Seaborn?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

For Seaborn lineplot, it seems pretty easy to plot the Standard Deviation by specifying `ci='sd'`. Is there a way to plot 2 times the standard deviation?

For example, I have a graph like this:

[image]

```
sns.lineplot(data=df, ax=x, x='day_of_week', y='y_variable', color='lightgrey', ci='sd')
```

Is there a way to make it so the "CI" plotted is 2 times the standard deviation?

Comment: Please provide an MCVE to initialize the dataframe. If seaborn is just doing `df.groupby('day_of_week')`, then you can replicate the calculation

Comment: Not in any current released version, but in the development version, [yes](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/pull/2407).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use custom error bar in seaborn lineplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56203420/how-to-use-custom-error-bar-in-seaborn-lineplot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a solution within the `seaborn`, but a walk-around way is by using [`matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between.html), as, e.g., was done in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58405328/6151828), but also in [the thread suggested in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56203420/how-to-use-custom-error-bar-in-seaborn-lineplot).

Here is my implementation:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.set_theme()

flights = sns.load_dataset("flights")
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12, 6), sharey=True)
sns.lineplot(data=flights, x="year", y = "passengers", ci="sd", ax=axs[0])
axs[0].set_title("seaborn")

means = flights.groupby("year")["passengers"].mean()
stds = flights.groupby("year")["passengers"].std()
axs[1].plot(means.index, means.values)
for nstd in range(1, 4):
    axs[1].fill_between(means.index, (means - nstd*stds).values, (means + nstd*stds).values, alpha=0.3, label="nstd={}".format(nstd))
axs[1].legend(loc="upper left")
axs[0].set_title("homemade")
plt.savefig("./tmp/flights.png")
plt.close(fig)
```

The resulting figure is
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Recent versions of seaborn (>v0.12) changed how to specify the error bar, and now allow passing a scale parameter together with the choice of error measurement (e.g., standard deviation).

Check this link [Statistical estimation and error bars](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/error_bars.html) for more info.

So, to plot 2x Standard Deviation in Seaborn you just need to pass this parameter: `errorbar=('sd', 2)`